# Excel (No VBA) - Convert a string to a cell index

Tags: excel, indexing, offset

I am trying to use the `OFFSET` function within the Excel sheet.

```
=OFFSET(ref, row , column)
```

In my case, the ref value is a string, as an example the cell `D12`.

```
=OFFSET("D12",0,1)
```

this formula won't work for me.

Do you know how to fix it by keeping a string as reference input ?

Comment: Look into INDIRECT function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use INDIRECT function like below:

`=OFFSET(INDIRECT("D12"),0,1)`

> **Caution**:
>
> Both functions are volatile and excess usage may affect performance of your workbook.